# can I add a mime type to a javascript encodeURIcomponent response?

Tags: javascript, excel, mime

I would like to generate an excel file with some visible data in a table I have.

I currently generate it like so:

```
$("#data_table tbody tr").filter(":visible").each(function(i,t){
        //iterate through rows and collect data         

        location.href='data:application/download,' + encodeURIComponent(data);
 });
```

Is it possible to define a mime-type for this response so it will be opened by excel?
This solution requires the browser to do "save as:" in order to open excel.

(Note: the rendering is currently not great either in the csv, I might skip this solution altogether and go through server side).

Answer (score 0):

Now that was easy :)

I had copied the code from somewhere else, and while now editing it a bit to create this post, I really started looking better at it.

location.href IS containing the mime type!
So the solution is:

```
location.href='data:application/vnd.ms-excel,' + encodeURIComponent(data)
```